# What does "fail successfully" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity

From reading the words it sounds like teaching someone how to fail, however I hear people use it to motivate others to succeed!. So what does the expression "fail successfully" mean?

Also, are there other expressions with similar meaning?

Comment: An example of the expression's use should be included in your question.

Comment: This question should be closed, as the OP has still not edited it with an example of the expression's use.

Answer (score 1):

The term **successful failure** is commonly used to refer to a failure or mistake which you learn and take the good from, so it is not a failure entirely as it has helped you progress and ensure you do not make the mistake again. **Fail sucessfully** is a derivation of this, using a verb and adverb instead of adjective and noun.